# Play the sound of $\pi$

Tags: sound

How do I play the sound of $\pi$?

There is code for the sound of random integers in $(-1,1)$.

```
Sound[SoundNote[#, 0.12] & /@ Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 100]]]
```

[image]

I tried:

```
Sound[SoundNote[#, 0.12] & /@ Accumulate[RealDigits[N[Pi, 100], 2]]]
```

[image]

but it doesn't work.

Comment: To mimic the random integer, you could try ternary digits minus 1: `Accumulate[First@RealDigits[Pi, 3, 100] - 1]]`

Comment: `Sound[SoundNote[#, 0.12] & /@ 
  Accumulate@First@RealDigits[N[Pi, 10], 2]]`

Comment: `Sound[SoundNote[#, 0.12] & /@ First@RealDigits[N[Pi, 100]]]` directly turns the digits into MIDI note numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how to "dial" the digits of $\pi$ on a touch tone phone (code adapted and modernized from [an old *Mathematica* demo](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Demos/SoundGallery/TouchTones.html), but see [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/09/01/touch-tone-telephone-dialing/) as well):

```
touchToneList = Tuples[{{697, 770, 852, 941}, {1209, 1336, 1477}}];
playTouchTone[phonenumber : {__Integer}] := Play[Evaluate[Piecewise[
    MapIndexed[{Total[Sin[2 π touchToneList[[#1]] t]],
                First[#2]/5 - 0.2 < t < First[#2]/5 - 0.1} &, 
               Mod[phonenumber, 11, 1]]]], {t, 0, Length[phonenumber]/5}]

playTouchTone[First[RealDigits[π, 10, 12]]]
```

[image: dialing pi]

Answer (score 1):

Closer to the given example is the following:

```
Sound[SoundNote[#, 0.12] & /@ RealDigits[\[Pi], 10, 10][[1]]]
```

[image]

Note that using `Accumulate` in this context would lead to a constantly rising "tune", which is probably not what you want.

If you really want to make the serialists proud, use base-12 instead of base-10. (Note: relies on unproven assertions about whether π is a normal number in base-12.)